# Monogame/Xna - Isometric view

Tags: 3d, xna, monogame

I'm trying to achieve an isometric effect in Monogame, what I have so far looks pretty good visually but I'm not sure the code I've written for the view and projection matrices is correct.

So this is what I've got for the Camera class:

```
    public class Camera
    {
        GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;

        public Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
        public Vector3 lookAtVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        public Matrix ViewMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                var upVector = Vector3.UnitZ;

                return Matrix.CreateLookAt(Vector3.Transform(position, Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), MathHelper.ToRadians(35), 0)),
                    Vector3.Transform(lookAtVector, Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians(45), MathHelper.ToRadians(35), 0)), 
                    upVector);
            }
        }

        public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return Matrix.CreateOrthographic(50, 38, -100, 500);
            }
        }

        public Camera(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        {
            this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

        }
    }
```

Which creates the following when I draw some tiles:

[image]

Now from what I've read, yaw should be 45 degrees and pitch should be 30 degrees to achieve the effect I'm looking for, but using the above code if I set pitch to 30 it looks distorted so I've had to bump it up to 35 and I think it looks ok.

I'm quite new to 3D programming so perhaps my approach isn't the best, any advice would be really appreciated. FYI I'm applying the transformation to the position and target vectors of the view matrix so that I'm able to move the camera around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "correct" is subjective. If it looks good to you then run with it. The only thing that might influence the "correctness" is if you decide you want to use some [2D isometric art assets](https://kenney.nl/assets?s=isometric) or something. In that case you'll probably want everything to fits together nicely. On the other hand if you're going for all 3D models it probably doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you have the 30° from. The correct elevation angle is about 35.3°.

If you use the `CreateLookAt` function, then there is a much simpler way because the view direction is always the cube diagonal. For this, let's suppose that your camera has a `target` position that it is looking at and a `viewDistance`. Then, the view matrix is:

```
Matrix.CreateLookAt(target + new Vector3(1, 1, -1) * viewDistance, target, upVector)
```

You can change the signs in the diagonal vector `(1, 1, -1)` to match the view you want.